# Downloading maven artifcats from azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have published all over gradle/maven artifacts to azure devops artifacts repository. Now, we want to use these artifacts in some of the scripts or python code. When i looked into the options to "Connect to feed", it only shows options specific to maven or gradle.

Can we rest calls or APIs to download specific artifacts from azure devops ?

Answer (score 1):

Apologize for the previous answer.

For rest API, of course it can. Refer to this doc first: [Maven - Download Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/maven/downloadpackage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

```
GET https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feed name}/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{fileName}/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

To download this in script, you can use powershell task to achieve it:

```
$strURL = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_apis/packaging/feeds/{feed name}/maven/{groupId}/{artifactId}/{version}/{fileName}/content?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$filePath="D:\"
$fileName=$filePath+"\build.{type}"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $strURL -Headers @{   
 Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
} -Method GET  -OutFile $fileName
```

Replace the relevant file type to specify it in the `$fileName=$filePath+"\build.{type}"`. After this script finished successfully, you can check your local file in the corresponding file path.

Comment: I want to use rest calls to download the artifact. Not by using maven pm.xml, etc

Comment: there are still some issues. How to get the latest version of snapshot maven package. 

In the REST call, i need to specify the exact file name .. which is not possible in case of snapshot versions

Comment: You can store some of them into the variable while you push this package, then use it in this download task.